# Is there a more efficient way to search columns of a data frame?

Tags: string, dataframe

Folks,

As the title says, I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to find a word in various strings residing in a data frame column. My solution is below.

```
total=0
for title in list(df['JobTitle']):
    total+=title.count('Chief')
total
```

Comment: Search can be done in parallel

Comment: In what language?